# Is there is any risk to use "public" modifier instead of "private" with my pojo fields?

Tags: java, coding-style, pojo

In my all `JSF` projects i use the standard definition of `Pojo`
As a `Plain Old Java Object` which define `private` modifier for fields

For Example

```
public class Pojo {

    // My private fields
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    // setters AND getters
    // ----------------------------
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }
    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }
    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
    // ---------------------------- 
}
```

Is there is any risk to use `public` modifier instead of `private` with my `Pojo` fields
For Example

```
public class Pojo {

    // My private fields
    public String field1;
    public String field2;

    // setters AND getters
    // ----------------------------
    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }
    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }
    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
    // ---------------------------- 
}
```

Note
I really need to do that (change modifier) not just for experiment

Comment: Well, `risk` is a vague term. It is certainly bad practice at least. Why would you really need to do this?

Comment: @Keppil: IMHO, a class which is nothing but a bunch of public fields and a few simple helper methods (e.g. `loadFrom`, which accepts a reference to another instance and copies all field values from it) should be regarded semantically much like a fixed-sized array which can hold a mixture of types, and whose elements are accessed by name rather than by number.  The security of a class which stores information in an `int[]` is not compromised by the fact that outside code can create `int[]` instances as well, unless references to its *instances* leak to outside code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "risk" is that you basically no longer have any control over the values. You can never enforce any kind of validation, because any code can change the value at any time.

Also, you can never change the *implementation detail* of how the data is stored, because you're making that public. With just the getters and setters, you've separated the API (what the class can do) from the implementation details.

Now you *may* decide that that's all fine (although I wouldn't). If you *do* go down the public field route, I would advise you to remove the getter/setter methods - otherwise anyone seeing the methods might *look* like you've got a "proper" class when really you've just got a data bucket.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a clear-cut answer and found it here!